# How to use a service instead of a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know how to use a service instead of a controller in an AngularJS1 app.

this is my controller, and I want to use a service because I want to have 2 controllers in my html, 1 for form and 1 for table list.

How should I do this?

Comment: Do you want to use a service to share data, isn't it? Have you checked the differents possibilities to share data between controller?

Comment: `factory` is the answer here.

Comment: Why do you need a service, when a controller works just as well? You can just use the same controller for each component, but have 2 instances of it. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: put your controller at body: <body ng-controller="usersCtrl">

Answer (score 2):

In AngularJS, a service should return it's API as a Javascript object, so a basic service will look like:

```
//filename: user.service.js

angular.module('app')
    .factory('userService', userService);

function userService() {
   return {
       sayHi
   };

   function sayHi() {
      alert('Hi');
   }
}
```

**Note:** it is a good convention to use `.factory` instead of `.service`. These components are almost the same so it is more common to use `factory`.

When you return a Javascript object you expose an API to the controllers, so calling a service inside a controller is like:

```
//filename: user.controller.js

angular.module('app')
    .controller('userCtrl', userCtrl);

function userCtrl($scope, userService) {
    $scope.sayHi = userService.sayHi;
}
```

This is how you will create a service, and how you will use its functions inside a controller.

Now if you need to have a list of users, then you need to declare the users array inside the service instead of declaring it inside the controller, and return the service API, so for example:

```
//filename: user.service.js

angular.module('app')
    .factory('userService', userService);

function userService() {
   var users = [];

   return {
       addUser,
       getUsers,
   };

   function addUser(user) {
      users.push({
        username: user.username,
        level: user.level,
        registrationStatus: user.registrationStatus,
        registrationDate: user.registrationDate
      });
   }

   function getUsers() {
      return users;
   }
}
```

Now you can access the method `userService.addUser(user)` from each controller and `userService.getUsers()` from each controller, you just have to include the service as a parameter for the controller as explained above.

A typical controller using this service will look like:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('UserCtrl', UserCtrl);

function UserCtrl($scope, userService) {

    $scope.addUser = addUser;
    $scope.users = userService.getUsers();

    function addUser(user) {
      userService.addUser(user);
      $scope.user = {};
    }
  });
```

The controller calls the `userService.addUser` whenever it needs to add a user to the list and calls `userService.getUsers` when it needs to retrieve the users from the service. Now the `users` array will be shared between all the controllers that using this service.

So a view using this controller will look like:

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">

  <form ng-submit="addUser(user)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.level">
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.username}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Of course, this is just a basic example and you can add your own functions and behaviors to the controller and to the service, but you can also use the examples as the base of your code.

That's it! if you need anything else I will be glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the service, please check this link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

In your case:

that can be:

```
myApp.service('userService',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.user = [];
    $scope.addUser = function () {...};
    ....
}])
```

and in your controllers:

```
myApp.controller('usersCtrl', function ($scope, userService) {
    $scope.user=userService.user;
    ...
}
```

But there is many ways to share data between controller. Simple google search will give you Answers.